# jboss 7.2 compatibility with primefaces and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, primefaces, jboss7.x

I need to know if primefaces 5.0.x and hibernate 4.3.6.FInal are supported by JBOSS7.2?
can you please link me up to an officlal compatibilty chart , as i must make sure the stack elements are all compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primefaces 5.0 is compatible with JSF2.0, JSF2.1 and JSF 2.2, then yes
see also this link https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673